# Is it possible to interpolate variables in Angular's innerHTML?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following in my template:

`<div [innerHTML]="dynamicMSG"></div>`

In my component I have a call to retrieve the dynamicMSG content from the DB. Let's say it returns something like this:

`dynamicMSG = <p>Your new code is: <strong>{{newCode}}</strong></p>` where newCode is a variable with value 123.

How can I make it render `123` instead of `{{newCode}}`? Is it possible to interpolate or do I need to use replace?

Thanks

Comment: Short answer: no, you can't. You would have to compile the html template, and the whole point of the AOT compilation is to do that at build time, and to avoid shipping the template compiler with the app.

Comment: If you *must* render HTML generated by the back-end using a handlebars style of templating, then maybe it's easier to just use Mustache if the extra weight of the JS saves you time and you don't mind using it. https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a better idea to use Angular's ng-template and ng-container pattern. You can then use interpolation inside the ng-template.

[Check this tutorial out](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/)